# Population column sort_values

Tags: python, pandas

tried all my best to see if this issue was discovered before, but could not see any so far, hence kindly asking to advise me what's wrong with my data frame?

```py
    df1=sample_data.sort_values("Population")
    df1
```

As I see, pandas sorted the values, but did not take into account superior digits in the 6 digits numbers;

Output:

```py
> city_id,Population 5573,123В 150 5177,127В 783 5589,129В 168
> 5568,132В 585 5600,193В 419 4755,1В 127В 200 5512,1В 153В 125
> 4825,1В 187В 831 4545,1В 648В 000 5681,1В 972В 375 5513,230В 443
> 5548,3В 375В 046 4536,490В 038 4757,515В 935 4756,556В 794
> 5535,575В 250 5291,698В 829 5249,844В 360 4534,866В 348 5528,914В 358
> 5536,926В 007
```

Thanks,
Evgeny.

Comment: [Please dont upload images in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Also share a reproducible example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Took out the image as you suggested, and put the csv

Comment: It seems like that only one column city_id is int64 type, and other columns are obj type, e.g. some columns should be % values, and they came as obj types when exported from excel alike spreadsheet; is there a way to convert these columns keeping their values ?

Comment: Eventually i have figured out, the issues was that in Russia Google spreadsheet uses comma delimited values, e.g. 0,01 while in the US 0.01 dot delimited values, and when I got csv file, then all comma delimited values became objects - or smth that in the " ... " that's why pandas could not sort out in a proper way as it would have done for the real numbers;